# Excel as Com Server is not released if the app is not properly closed

Tags: c++, excel, com

I am using Excel automation in C++ (EXE) that is listening to Excel events.
Once the user opens the Excel app, I am able to reference the _Application pointer via the `AccessibleObjectFromWindow` function.
After this - I am able to connect to the `IID_IConnectionPointContainer` and get the various events.

My issue is the following: If my program crashes (or if I stop the debugger), I am not able to properly clean the `_Application` pointer, so Excel.EXE is still running even if the user has closed the program. 
This makes sense since the `_Application` ref count is still 1.

However, if the user opens the Excel.EXE again -> It starts without any add-ins. The user needs to manually add the ribbons.
This behaviour will continue until the Excel.EXE is manually killed.

Did anyone experience such an issue? 
Is there a way to clean COM object pointers after my app crashes?

Comment: How do you add your addin ? via the "COM Addin" button or via the "Add-ins" dialog box ? If it is via the COM Addin button, you can set a registry key to force to load automatically your addin. see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291392/excel-com-add-ins-and-automation-add-ins . In this latter case, if your addin crashes excel, then at next startup excel will ask the user if he wants to deactivate this addin. This won't fix the problem related to the hidden Excel.exe process but you won't be forced to manually add the addin.

Comment: I'm confused, one minute you are saying your code is an app (exe) and then you start talking about add-ins. The only way I can think of when Word disables an add-in is when a crash occurs in your code in an _add-in_ **not** not because of some Ole Automation client (your exe) crashes

Comment: My code is an EXE file that attaches to an existing Excel process - it's not an add-in. However, there are other add-ins on the computer that are not related to my code. If my EXE crashes (it's cant crash Excel, since it's in other process), the Excel EXE keeps running even if the user closes it. Next time the user runs Excel - the add-ins are not there.